# Bill Reference Number not populating in Xero API

Tags: xero-api

I'm creating a bill (supplier invoice) in Xero API (C# .Net). Everything populates perfectly except for the Reference number which remains blank.

Excerpt:

```
var invoiceObject = new Invoice
{
    Reference = "TEST123", 
    Contact = contact,
    Date = DateTime.Now,
    DueDate = DateTime.Now,
    ExpectedPaymentDate = DateTime.Now,
    Status = Xero.Api.Core.Model.Status.InvoiceStatus.Draft,
    LineItems = lineItems,
    Type = Xero.Api.Core.Model.Types.InvoiceType.AccountsPayable
};

var invoice = api.Invoices.Create(invoiceObject);
```

The following screenshot demonstrates the issue:

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Every other field, lineitem, tax code, etc. populates perfectly.

I've tried different combinations of upper and lowercase characters, numbers, etc. but it doesn't work.

If I log in to Xero, open the Invoice and manually enter `TEST123` an save the invoice, it works perfectly.

I've also tried saving the invoice, then editing it and re-saving in the API and the reference still does not populate.

How can I set the reference in the API?

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same issue. I'm using Python Xero but hopefully, it is the same for Javascript.

In my case, I have to use InvoiceNumber instead of Reference for bills.

Answer (score 1):

### Quick answer

[Xero Invoice API docs](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/invoices) indicate that you can't set the reference value for an ACCPAY invoice, but that whatever you put for the Invoice Number (which is a non-unique field on ACCPAY Invoices) will also appear in the reference field.

### Explanation

I ran into this same issue. I found this comment on Xero's support forum:

https://community.xero.com/developer/discussion/40489223

... which says this:

> Reference is presently slightly differently based on whether the
>   invoice is a sales invoice (ACCREC) or a purchase invoice/bill
>   (ACCPAY). For a bill the reference is presented in the InvoiceNumber
>   element, check our documentation on invoices [here](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/invoices) where we explain
>   this in more detail.

### From the linked to docs

[image: Invoice API Doc notes]

All that said, the screenshot you include in your post does have a "reference" input on it, but that's not an input for the invoice's reference value - that's an input for a possible reference value for a payment you enter against the invoice. The reference value for an invoice appears at the top next to the due date:

[image]